# spring boot Ojdbc6 class not found

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, intellij-idea, ojdbc

My project settings are SpringBoot4+Mybatis+Oracle10g.This project clearly requires a ojdbc driver. So I installed Ojdbc6 into local maven repository first with the command.

```
mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dpackaging=jar -Dversion=11.2.0.4 -Dfile=ojdbc6.jar -DgeneratePom=true
```

Then I import it in the pom file like this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Ater that,i reimported the project dependencies and found that `ojdbc6.jar` showed up in the external libraries. All seemed to be perfect except when I try to run codes that fetches data from Oracle, this error appeared

```
2018-05-01 15:57:33.709 [http-nio-8080-exec-8] ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load class: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver from ClassLoader:sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2;ClassLoader:TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2

    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:283)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
```

It doesn't make any sense to me.How could it not be able to load jdbc class when `ojdbc.jar` is clearly in the classpath?

Comment: How are you running the code? From IntelliJ or from the command line?

Comment: Intellij professional version

Comment: Isn't the driver class `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver` instead of `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` looks like wrong configuration. Also please add the full stacktrace not only a snippet.

Comment: If you are deploying to Tomcat via IDE, make sure you have added this jar into an [artifact](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html) which you then deploy. And of course make sure you are specifying the correct driver class name as @M.Deinum pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Goto directory structure of your project where `pom.xml` lies and run following command

> mvn spring-boot:run

if this successfully runs server then there is problem of classpath only.

Answer (score 0):

Run this command `mvn -U idea:idea`. This command will add ojdbc jar into your IntelliJ classpath.

Comment: It's not working.i I still get the same error even though this command was successfully executed.